# Ubuntu Installation finished successfully, but by the time I restart, ubuntu is gone

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, dell

I recently tried installing ubuntu with windows using the "Install with Windows Boot Manager" option, it eventually finished successfully. So before restarting, I went into GParted, and as I expected, ubuntu was installed in the unallocated space I previously made. But when I restarted, my dell laptop would not boot into it. So I booted into windows and opened up Disk Management, and space, where ubuntu was installed, was unallocated space as if the installation never happened, what may be causing this and how can I fix it

Comment: I've never seen "Install with Windows Boot Manager" option. What is the Ubuntu version? It is OK that Windows shows Ubuntu as unallocated. Windows can't see linux partitions.

Comment: I mean in this option: https://linuxhint.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/14-13.png. Also, though this is a 18.4 screenshot, I was trying to install 20.04. Also, the last time  I installed ubuntu, windows was able to detect the partition.